# Excel function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out the problem with the following formula down here. The output in my Excel file is =@SLUMP() - but I want to get a random number in cell (6,3).

My Excel is in Swedish and I don't know if this might disturb the VBA.

```
Sub test6()

Worksheets("Blad2").Cells(6, 3).Formula = "=SLUMP()"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `= "=Rand()"`

Comment: Change `.Formula`  to `.FormulaLocal` or perhaps `.Formula2Local` if you don't want the `@`.

Comment: @Warcupine your worked thank you!